# Clearing bootstrap editable forms

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I am currently using bootstrap editable for the front end of my application.

See plugin: http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/index.html

What I am doing is loading data onto a page via Ajax and allowing each item on the page to be editable. For example; I load a user onto a page and allows for his first name, last name and date of birth to be editable.

Because I am loading via Ajax, when a second user is loaded for example or third and i try to edit the first name etc, I keep getting the values of the first user loaded initially.

I am presuming it may be cache. I have tried setting display on the function and even auto-text.

Is there anyway I can reset or clear the editable form?

see sample code below:

```
function editable(obj) {
    $('#title, #lastName, #firstName).editable('option', {
       pk: obj.lId,
       placement: 'bottom',
       emptytext: 'Empty',
       display: function(value) {
         $(this).text(value);
        },
       validate: function(value) {
         if ($.trim(value) === '') {
            return 'This field is required';
         }
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: the different users info are displayed on the same public page ?

Comment: Yes. admin can search a user and that info is loaded via ajax.

Comment: You are showing your code for how you initialize x-editable, but not how you are updating the fields with ajax. Please show that code, as it looks like that is where your error is

Comment: you're sure it is not a backend issue. Otherwise, you should post your entire code to let us debug. Posssible problem : you should use `class` instead of `ids`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `obj` is your new user, and it contains the title, last name, and first name of the new user, all you have to do is set the values of the x-editable objects:

```
$('#title').editable('setValue', obj.title);
$('#lastName').editable('setValue', obj.lastName);
$('#firstName').editable('setValue', obj.firstName);
```

The reason why your example is not working is because x-editable separates the display from the actual value. Your `display` function is called whenever the user changes an x-editable value. By default, x-editable displays whatever the value is set to. But perhaps the internal value is different from a displayed value, that is what the `display` function is used for - it has no impact on the actual value, just the display of the value.

X-Editable has a lot of different methods you can take advantage of, you can find them on the 'Methods' tab here: http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable